# Share a module between processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, tweepy

I have a program, which starts a tweepy streamListener, which adds new tweets to a database and starts another process which monitors said database for tweets older than X and does something with them.

The code below is structurally similar, just without the database interaction code, as it is not the thing causing my problem.

The problem, from what I understand is, that you can't share python modules that hold some kind of state between the different processes.

How do I work around this? I need both processes to have access to tweepy for twitter interaction.

Any help or ideas are much appreciated!

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import tweepy

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        keys = {
            "consumer_key": "",
            "consumer_secret": "",
            "access_token": "",
            "access_token_secret": ""
        }

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys['consumer_key'], keys['consumer_secret'])
        auth.set_access_token(keys['access_token'], keys['access_token_secret'])

        self.api = tweepy.API(auth)

        self.worker = Worker(self.api)

    def run(self):
        self.worker.start()

        myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=self.api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
        stream.filter(track=['python'], async=True)

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, api):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

        self.api = api

    def run(self):
        # Filler for debugging purposes
        print(self.api.me(), flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        # Filler for debugging purposes
        print(status.text, flush=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = App()
    APP.run()
```

Running this produces the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[PATH_REMOVED]", line 46, in <module>
    APP.run()
  File "[PATH_REMOVED]", line 22, in run
    self.worker.start()
  File "E:\Programs\Python 3.x\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "E:\Programs\Python 3.x\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "E:\Programs\Python 3.x\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "E:\Programs\Python 3.x\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "E:\Programs\Python 3.x\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Programs\Python 3.x\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "E:\Programs\Python 3.x\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: seems like your `module` has no permissions , please change the the permissions of the `module` file to read,write,execute.